# Help with hijacked dns

Tags: 17.10, dns, malware

When I try to navigate to a domain that I know doesn't exist, I automatically get routed to advexplore dot com which shows me a search bar and genealogy links. This is obviously not a default situation so I'm either suffering from malware on a fresh install of 17.10, somehow, my DNS has been hijacked, or the ISP is the culprit. I'm not sure which nor how to check.

I've tried changing my DNS to google (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) in the wifi settings, but my computer seems to be ignoring it.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 209.222.18.222
nameserver 209.222.18.218
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. try one of the many websites that do DNS resolution. Some even let you try out different nameservers, or try several on their own
2. backup your `/etc/resolve.conf` (it usually is just a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`) and manually create your own with some other nameserver e.g.
   `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf`
   (don't forget to revert to original `resolv.conf` aftwerwards)
3. use nslookup and specifiy a nameserger
   `nslookup suspicious-domain.com 8.8.8.8

Comment: I've tried various iterations of this, and no matter what I still end up with at least one corporate search or dns ip, like `search cpe.tdp.com` I can't figure out where it's coming from!